# Filter out all rows with only one period in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this column, `Identifier` with character values.

```
structure(list(Identifier = c("RL.K", "RL.K.1", "RL.K.2", "RL.K.3", 
"RL.K.4", "RL.K.5", "RL.K.6", "RL.K.7", "RL.K.9", "RL.K.10", 
"RI.K", "RI.K.1", "RI.K.2", "RI.K.3", "RI.K.4", "RI.K.5", "RI.K.6", 
"RI.K.7", "RI.K.9", "RI.K.10", "RF.K", "RF.K.1")), row.names = c(NA, 
-22L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

How do I filter out the values with only one period? so that I can take out rows 1, 11, and 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can count the number of `.` in the 'Identifier' and create a logical condition for `filter`ing the rows

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   filter(str_count(Identifier, "[.]") == 1)
# A tibble: 3 x 1
#  Identifier
#  <chr>     
#1 RL.K      
#2 RI.K      
#3 RF.K
```

Or as @WiktorStribizew mentioned, `fixed` can be wrapped to make it more faster

```
df1 %>% 
   filter(str_count(Identifier, fixed(".")) == 1)
```

---

Or without using any external libraries,

```
df1[nchar(gsub("[^.]*", "", df1$Identifier)) == 1,]
```

Or using `gregexpr` from `base R`

```
df1[lengths(gregexpr(".", df1$Identifier, fixed = TRUE)) == 1,]
```

Comment: Why regex? There is just a dot to find, use `str_count(Identifier, fixed("."))`

Comment: Wow, that was a quickie!

Answer (score 2):

A solution using base R. (find all strings with exactly one dot)

```
grepl("^[^.]*[.][^.]*$", df1$Identifier)
```

---

To remove the rows with one dot use:

```
df1[
!grepl("^[^.]*[.][^.]*$", df1$Identifier),
]
```

Comment: it nees a `!` in front of `grepl` expression, since you want to filter out those with only one `.` for which the regex is searching.

Comment: thanks @Gwang-JinKim. I just realized "filter out" meant "remove".

Answer (score 2):

If we're going to use base and grepl, there's a simpler regex code:

```
df[grepl("\\..*\\.", df$Identifier),]
```

(explanation for the regex: `\\.` finds a literal ., `.*` finds anything, so this code finds cases where there are two literal dots separated by anything)

Answer (score 0):

With as little Regex as possible ;):

```
has.only.one.dot <- function(str_vec) sapply(strsplit(str_vec, "\\."), function(vec) length(vec) == 2)
df[!has.only.one.dot(df$Identifier), ]
```

However, the list functions `sapply` and `strsplit` are slower than regex solution.

```
has.only.one.dot <- function(str_vec) grepl("\\.", str_vec) & ! grepl("\\..*\\.", str_vec)
df[!has.only.one.dot(df$Identifier), ]
```